# ORTools SAT alternative to CS IntVar[].Element(IntExpr index) to cost reciprocal assignments

Tags: c#, or-tools, sat

I'm trying to assign costs if there is a "reciprocal" assignment in an IntVar[].  Here's how I've accomplished it in the older ConstraintSolver...

```cs
IntVar[] assignments = solver.MakeIntVarArray(size, 0, size-1, "assignments");
var cost = Enumerable.Range(0, size)
    .Select(i => 999 * (assignments.Element(assignments[i]) == i))
    .ToArray()
    .ToSum()
    .Var();
var objective = cost.Minimize(1);
```

Now I'm trying to use the newer `CpSolver` in `Google.OrTools.Sat` where the `.Element` extension is absent (I assume for good reason).  I've managed to get it to "work" using four IntVars[] but I suspect this is just a big modeling fail on my part.

```cs
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, size))
{
    model.AddElement(assignments[i], assignments, reciprocals[i]);
    model.Add(reciprocals[i] == i).OnlyEnforceIf(reciprocalBools[i]);
    model.Add(reciprocals[i] != i).OnlyEnforceIf(reciprocalBools[i].Not());
    model.Add(costs[i] == 999).OnlyEnforceIf(reciprocalBools[i]);
    model.Add(costs[i] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(reciprocalBools[i].Not());
}
model.Minimize(costs.Sum());
```

Based on my testing, the above seems to be functionally correct, however as `size` gets larger, the SAT version of my test app performs orders of magnitude worse than the CS version.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

here is a better version

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, size))
{
    model.AddElement(assignments[i], assignments, reciprocals[i]);
    model.Add(reciprocals[i] == i).OnlyEnforceIf(reciprocalBools[i]);
    model.Add(reciprocals[i] != i).OnlyEnforceIf(reciprocalBools[i].Not());
}
model.Minimize(999 * LinearExpr.Sum(reciprocalBools));
```

We also have a Inverse constraint (`model.AddInverseConstraint(x_array, y_array)`)
that enforces

```
x_array[i] == j <=> y_array[j] == i
```

Still I wonder if you need all these.

If `xi = {xi_1, .., xi_n}` (mapping to a Boolean variable array)
`reciprocalBools[i] is true` iff  `exists j, such that (xi_j && xj_i) is true`

So you just need to count the pairs `(xi_j && xj_i)` both true.

This is not straightforward.

given i and j, i != j

```
Literal implied = model.newBoolVar("");
model.addBoolOr(new Literal[] {xi_j.not(), xj_i.not(), implied});
model.addImplication(implied, xi_j);
model.addImplication(implied, xj_i);
```

Now, you have `implied <=> xi_j && xj_i`. And you can count these `implied` variables.

if i == j, do not create the `implied` variable, do not add the 3 Boolean constraint, and use xi_i directly.

Comment: I would like to take the chance to thank you for your insightful comments of yesterday, it has been a valuable learning chance for me. :)

Comment: Thanks.  As a valuable source of information, I recommend this slide deck https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/pstuckey/PPDP2013.pdf . Although there are some discrepancies with the CP-SAT implementation. The general idea is here.

Comment: Thanks Laurent, but I can't find the `LinearExpr.Sum()` method in 7.1.6720 nuget package.  The class `Google.OrTools.LinearSolver.LinearExpr` has no static methods.

Comment: Why are you using the LinearSolver ? This is a CP-SAT code. Thus `Google.OrTools.Sat.LinearExpr`.

Comment: Your first block is what I ended up with after your comment in @PatrickTrentin 's post to scale the costs outside.  I've been trying to work with a jagged array of Boolean instead of the IntVar, but can't seem to do the things you suggest.  `model.NewBoolVar` creates `IntVar` and if I try to `(xi_j && xj_i)` or `(xi_j * xj_i)` it won't compile `operator cannot be applied to operands IntVar and IntVar`

Comment: I'm not using the LinearSolver.  `Google.OrTools.Sat.LinearExpr` does not exist in my package so I'm trying to figure out what you are suggesting.

Comment: There is a `Google.OrTools.Sat.LinearExpression` class, but it doesn't have a static `Sum()` method either.

Comment: Are you using 7.1 ? This was introduces in 7.1. And in java, it is called sum().

Comment: About the &&, this was pseudo code. I have added the corresponding code.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 7.1.6720

Comment: Thanks a lot Laurent, I was able to get the reciprocals working with the implied variables per your suggestion. Early testing shows the bool matrix performs better than the integer array, but not as good as the version using ConstraintSolver.